# How can I migrate KDE plasma 4 settings to plasma 5?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04

recently, I upgraded to Kubuntu 15.04, which installs KDE plasma 5 by default, as I learned later. After logging in, all my desktop settings are gone (wallpaper, mini apps, panels). Is there a way to migrate my "old" plasma 4 desktop settings to plasma 5?

Thank you for reading.